# Remove digits around a certain punctuation mark with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to remove digits that attached to a punctuation mark, but it fails:

```
a = 'Car 1234 5678;91012 14567'
```

and I need to get:

```
a_new = 'Car 1234 14567'
```

I tried: `re.sub('\d{4}\;\d{5}', '', ss)` and it worked, however, I don't know how many digits I many have around `;`, so I tried:

`re.sub('\d\;\d', '', ss)` and it fails (the output is the same as input).

I'm studying regex101.com, but still no luck yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
import re

a = 'Car 1234 5678;91012 14567'

print(re.sub('\d*;\d* ', '', a))

#'Car 1234 14567'
```

Note the trailing space at the end of the re pattern. It will lead to only one space left in the middle instead of two.

Comment: Brilliant! I was hoping to remove the trailing space by chaining with: `.replace('  ', ' ')` thanks for this great suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do a :

```
import re
a='Car 1234 5678;91012 14567'

re.sub("[0-9]*;[0-9]*","",a)
```

Output:

```
'Car 1234  14567'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use + to indicate more digits as below.

```
a = 'Car 1234 5678;91012 14567'
re.sub('\d+;\d+ ','',a)
```

Output:

```
'Car 1234 14567'
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex that you've used `\d;\d` should work but it will only substitute the numbers immediately surrounding the semi colon as \d indicates one digit.

Your solution will be `\d+;\d+` with the addition symbol looking for at least one, but as many as there are, digits.

so...

```
a = 'Car 1234 5678;91012 14567'

re.sub('\d+;\d+ ', '', a)
```

returns

```
'Car 1234  14567'
```